# jQuery validate, only accept a latex file

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am working with a form in jQuery and using jQuery validate, I'd like the form to only accept a latex file and I went through the documentation and attempted to use the accept method https://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/.

From my understanding here https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Accept needs a mime type, and the mime type for latex is `"application/x-latex"`

So I have my form set up like the following

```js
$('#adminLatexUpload').validate({
  rules: {
    file: {
      required: true,
      accept: "application/x-latex"
    },
    version: {
      required: true,
      pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.\/]*$/
    }
  },

  messages: {
    file: {
      accept: "Unsupported file type, you must upload a .latex file"
    },
    version: {
      pattern: "Invalid naming convention, no whitespaces or special characters"
    }
  },

  errorElement: "span", // error tag name

  errorPlacement: function(error, element) { // rules for placement of error tag
    element.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
    error.addClass('help-block');
    error.appendTo(element.parent());
  },

  success: function(error, element) { // rules for placement of success tag
    error.removeClass('help-block');
    error.parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    error.remove();
  },

  submitHandler: function(form, e) {
    document.write('Good');
  },

  invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
    var errorCount = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errorCount) {
      var errMessage = errorCount === 1 ? "You have 1 error." : "You have " + errorCount + " errors."
      window.confirm(errMessage);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4 latex-container">
  <h4>Upload new Latex File</h4>
  <form class="form-vertical" id="adminLatexUpload">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">
                                        Attach Latex File:
                                        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="adminLatexUpload_File" accept=".tex" required />
                                    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">
                                        Version Name:
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="version" id="adminLatexUpload_Version" required />
                                    </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="adminLatexUpload_Submit" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> Upload</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Currently the page just refreshes when I click the submit button if I have both fields filled out. The text field validates as expected. But the input field exhibits quite a bit of undefined behavior.

Currently my testing has revealed the following:
[image: img error]
 - Adding a non-latex file (.jpg and .gif) don't trigger any validation
   response

- Submitting the file with a non-tex file refreshes the
- Trying to submit the form without a file trips the requires error,
  uploading a wrong file should give me a different error message and
  it doesn't, the required error persists

2 of these are pointing to the fact that the accept method is failing, but no scenario should force a page refresh.

What is wrong with my validate method? And what is causing this page refresh?

**Edit**
After taking the suggestion to add `debug:true` I get the following console error on submit of invalid file

Comment: describe undefined behavior in the input field.

Comment: If the page refreshes it means that the validate plugin setup has failed. Try adding `debug: true` to the options, and then check the console for errors when you submit the form. Also, never, ever use `document.write`

Comment: @Jason I editted my question to define my tests, their expected behavior and what I am seeing

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well the code in the handler is to send data to an api and do some processing to the results but that function is working fine without the validation. It's just this part that is causing the problem so I commented it out and just have this as a test

Comment: Well I ran it with debugger and I can see that the accept method is giving me the error, but I still don't understand how to fix it. It just tells me without a doubt that the accept property fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that the `accept` validator is in the additional methods file and not in the core. So you need to include the `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/additional-methods.min.js` file.

Still, the test i performed has the type of `.tex` as empty string, while if i pass a `.latex` file it is correctly identified as `application/x-latex` which seems to be the correct extension according to the link you posted.

So you might want to change the `accept` attribute on the input as well to `accept=".latex"`

```js
$('#adminLatexUpload').validate({
  rules: {
    file: {
      required: true,
      accept: "application/x-latex"
    },
    version: {
      required: true,
      pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.\/]*$/
    }
  },

  messages: {
    file: {
      accept: "Unsupported file type, you must upload a .latex file"
    },
    version: {
      pattern: "Invalid naming convention, no whitespaces or special characters"
    }
  },

  errorElement: "span", // error tag name

  errorPlacement: function(error, element) { // rules for placement of error tag
    element.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
    error.addClass('help-block');
    error.appendTo(element.parent());
  },

  success: function(error, element) { // rules for placement of success tag
    error.removeClass('help-block');
    error.parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    error.remove();
  },

  submitHandler: function(form, e) {
    document.write('Good');
  },

  invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
    var errorCount = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errorCount) {
      var errMessage = errorCount === 1 ? "You have 1 error." : "You have " + errorCount + " errors."
      window.confirm(errMessage);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4 latex-container">
  <h4>Upload new Latex File</h4>
  <form class="form-vertical" id="adminLatexUpload">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">
                                        Attach Latex File:
                                        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="adminLatexUpload_File" accept=".latex" required />
                                    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">
                                        Version Name:
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="version" id="adminLatexUpload_Version" required />
                                    </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="adminLatexUpload_Submit" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> Upload</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed the darn additional.js include. I misread the docs and thought that was a built in feature for the rules propof the validate object